# All products are not propely adjusted on home page

Tags: product-list

I have a problem in adjusting all the products in proper way. Some products are two line name and some products are one line name so it is showing not a great impact on customer. Can we add one extra line before add to cart button so it will show in one line.

Any idea will be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy solution for this problem is, adding a `min-height` CSS property to the product name enclosing `div` element.

In default Magento, product name is rendered like this.

File : `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
 <div class="product-name">
      <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
 </div>
```

So add a css rule like this

```
.product-name {
    min-height: 50px; //put an appropriate value here.
}
```

I am not a frontend expert, but this is what comes to my mind first. Very easy solution.

Comment: It's my pleasure.